One out of three fluent-bit daemons fails with "Failed to parse date field"
I have a 3-node Kubernetes cluster. Each of those nodes runs a FluentBit daemon which parses logs and sends them to OpenSearch on another cluster.
Two daemons run fine, the third however fails after a while, after being started. I looked at the errors and it seems that this might be the error that makes it fail:
2024/10/18 18:47:14] [error] [output:opensearch:opensearch.0] error: Output
{"took":2,"errors":true,"items":[{"create":{"_index":"fluent-bit-000005","_id":"xrD0oJIBZWCTFqHlkBw0","status":400,"error":{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to parse field [kubernetes.annotations.createdAt] of type [date] in document with id 'xrD0oJIBZWCTFqHlkBw0'. Preview of field's value: '2024-08-04 14:21:56'","caused_by":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"failed to parse date field [2024-08-04 14:21:56] with format [strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis]","caused_by":{"type":"date_time_parse_exception","reason":"Failed to parse with all enclosed parsers"}}}}},{"create":{"_index":"fluent-bit-000005","_id":"yLD0oJIBZWCTFqHlkBw0","status":400,"error":{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to parse field [kubernetes.annotations.createdAt] of type [date] in document with id 'yLD0oJIBZWCTFqHlkBw0'. Preview of field's value: '2024-08-04 14:21:56'","caused_by":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"failed to parse date field [2024-08-04 14:21:56] with format [strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis]","caused_by":{"type":"date_time_parse_exception","reason":"Failed to parse with all enclosed parsers"}}}}}]}

Not sure, but it seems it might have stumbled upon a log with a timestamp it doesn't know how to interpret. And it's failing.
How do I fix this ?
I expected for fluentbit pod to properly handle fields it cannot interpret and not fail. The fluent-bit configmap has the following config:
  custom_parsers.conf: |
    [PARSER]
        Name docker_no_time
        Format json
        Time_Keep Off
        Time_Key time
        Time_Format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L
  fluent-bit.conf: |
    [SERVICE]
        Daemon Off
        Flush 1
        Log_Level info
        Parsers_File parsers.conf
        Parsers_File custom_parsers.conf
        HTTP_Server On
        HTTP_Listen 0.0.0.0
        HTTP_Port 2020
        Health_Check On

    [INPUT]
        Name tail
        Path /var/log/containers/*.log
        multiline.parser docker, cri
        Tag kube.*
        Mem_Buf_Limit 100MB
        Buffer_Chunk_Size 256KB
        Buffer_Max_Size 2048KB
        Skip_Long_Lines On
    [FILTER]
        Name kubernetes
        Match kube.*
        Merge_Log Off
        Keep_Log On
        K8S-Logging.Parser On
        K8S-Logging.Exclude On
        Buffer_Size 2048KB
    [FILTER]
        Name modify
        Match kube.*
        Add cluster "f3e08809-c61b-4d5f-b6a3-539a328ef163"

    [OUTPUT]
        Name opensearch
        Match kube.*
        Index  fluent-bit
        Buffer_Size 256KB
        tls On
        tls.verify Off
        HTTP_User admin
        HTTP_Passwd <mypassword>
        Suppress_Type_Name On
        Replace_Dots On
        Trace_Error On
        Trace_Output On
        Log_Level info
        #Do not use dynamic discovery
        Host observability-opensearch-endpoint-skupper.my-agents
        Port 9200

